# ServiceAccount unable to delete a deployment or service, but is able to create it

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Kubernetes v1.20.0 , on Ubuntu 20.04.1, docker 19.3.11

Using the following configuration I am able to create a deployment in the namespace "live" using this serviceaccount's token, but I am unable to delete the deployment using the same token.

Trying to find the correct Role to bind to my programmatic ServiceAccount user, but I am unable to get the correct role mapping for deployment deletion.  I've tried with and without slashes, asterisks in the resource names, and pluralizing the Resources.

Here's the error i get from the API:

```
  warnings.warn(
Exception (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'xxxx-bf2f-43b3-af5d-3ce15b086080', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'xxxx-0d42-4b08-820e-396249f74107', 'Date': 'Mon, 28 Dec 2020 13:33:00 GMT', 'Content-Length': '408'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"deployments.apps \"live-stream-deploy-testing123\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:live:live-serviceaccount\" cannot delete resource \"deployments\" in API group \"apps\" in the namespace \"live\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"live-stream-deploy-testing123","group":"apps","kind":"deployments"},"code":403}
```

Here is the deployment i'm trying to delete:

```
$ kubectl -n live get deploy
NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
live-stream-deploy-testing123   1/1     1            1           76m
```

Here's where i'm currently at with my role definition ( I have tried with asterisks in Resource Names as well this did not work for create, many iterations later:):

```
$ kubectl -n live describe role
Name:         live-serviceaccount-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources          Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------          -----------------  --------------  -----
  deployment/        []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployment         []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployments/       []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployments        []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  service/           []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  service            []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  services/          []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  services           []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  services           []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployment.apps/   []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployment.apps    []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployments.apps/  []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  deployments.apps   []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  service.apps/      []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  service.apps       []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  services.apps/     []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
  services.apps      []                 []              [get watch create list delete]
```

Role binding:

```
$ kubectl -n live describe rolebindings
Name:         live-serviceaccount-rolebinding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  live-serviceaccount-role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                 Namespace
  ----            ----                 ---------
  ServiceAccount  live-serviceaccount  live
```

pip package kubernetes==12.0.1.  I have not tested it against a previous version.
Script that results in error:

```
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "live-stream-deploy-testing123" 

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = "service account token here..."
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.verify_ssl = False

configuration.host = "https://my_k8s_API:6443"

with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:

    try:
        api_instance = kubernetes.client.AppsV1Api(api_client)
        api_instance.delete_namespaced_deployment(
            name=DEPLOYMENT_NAME, namespace="live")
        logger.info("Deployment deleted. %s" % DEPLOYMENT_NAME)

    except ApiException as e:
        logger.error("Exception %s\n" % e)
```

Some additional "can-i" action:

```
$ kubectl -n live auth can-i  --as=system:serviceaccount:live:live-serviceaccount delete deploy
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i --as=system:serviceaccount:live:live-serviceaccount  --list -n live
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                                    []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                                    []               [create]
deployment/                                     []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployment                                      []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployments/                                    []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployments                                     []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
service/                                        []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
service                                         []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
services/                                       []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
services                                        []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployment.apps/                                []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployment.apps                                 []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployments.apps/                               []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
deployments.apps                                []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
service.apps/                                   []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
service.apps                                    []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
services.apps/                                  []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
services.apps                                   []                                    []               [get watch create list delete]
                                                [/.well-known/openid-configuration]   []               [get]
                                                [/api/*]                              []               [get]
                                                [/api]                                []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]                             []               [get]
                                                [/apis]                               []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []               [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []               [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]                          []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]                            []               [get]
                                                [/openid/v1/jwks]                     []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []               [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []               [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []               [get]
                                                [/version]                            []               [get]
                                                [/version]                            []               [get]
```

Here are the YAMLs that produced the above outputs.  They are all on the live namespace.  Forgive the mess on the roles, but I've been trying to iterate through to a solution:

```
$ cat role.yaml 
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: live-serviceaccount-role
  namespace: live
rules:
- apiGroups: ["","apps"] 
  resources: ["services", "services/", "deployment", "deployment/", "service", "service/", "deployments", "deployments/"]
  resourceNames: [""]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "create", "list", "delete"]
- apiGroups: [""] 
  resources: ["services"]
  resourceNames: [""]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "create", "list", "delete"]

$ cat serviceaccount.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: live-serviceaccount
  namespace: live

$ cat rolebinding.yaml 
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: live-serviceaccount-rolebinding
  namespace: live
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: live-serviceaccount # "name" is case sensitive
  namespace: live
roleRef:
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: live-serviceaccount-role # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
```

Here is a sample of the script that successfully lights up the deployment in the live namespace:

```
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes import client
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "live-stream-deploy-testing123"
POD_APP_LABEL = "lab"

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()

# Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = "service account token here..."
# Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
configuration.verify_ssl = False

# Defining host is optional and default to http://localhost
configuration.host = "https://<myk8sapi>:6443"

# Enter a context with an instance of the API kubernetes.client
#with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
with kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:

    api_instance = kubernetes.client.AppsV1Api(api_client)

    def create_deployment_object():
        # Configureate Pod template container
        container = kubernetes.client.V1Container(
            name="lab-container",

            # redacted for privacy
            image="nginx:latest",

            termination_message_path="/var/log/messages",
            image_pull_policy="IfNotPresent",
            resources=client.V1ResourceRequirements(
                requests={"memory": "5Gi"},
                limits={"memory": "16Gi"}
            ),
            volume_mounts=[
                client.V1VolumeMount(mount_path="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template", name="nginxconftemplate", sub_path="nginx.conf")
            ]
        )
        volume1 = client.V1Volume(
            name="nginxconftemplate",
            config_map=client.V1ConfigMapVolumeSource(
                name="live-nginx-conf",
                default_mode=0o0777
            )
        )
        # Create and configurate a spec section
        template = client.V1PodTemplateSpec(
            metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(labels={"app": POD_APP_LABEL}),
            spec=client.V1PodSpec(containers=[container],
                                  volumes=[volume1],
                                  node_selector={"backend": "yes"},
                                  )
        )
        # Create the specification of deployment
        spec = client.V1DeploymentSpec(
            replicas=1,
            template=template,
            selector={'matchLabels': {'app': POD_APP_LABEL}})
        # Instantiate the deployment object
        deployment = client.V1Deployment(
            api_version="apps/v1",
            kind="Deployment",
            metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=DEPLOYMENT_NAME),
            spec=spec)

        return deployment

    def create_deployment(api_instance, deployment):
        # Create deployement
        api_response = api_instance.create_namespaced_deployment(
            body=deployment,
            namespace="live")
        logger.info("Deployment created. status='%s'" % str(api_response.status))

    deployment = create_deployment_object()
    create_deployment(api_instance, deployment)
```

Comment: Can you provide yaml config files (service account, role and role binding)?

Comment: I have provided the yaml config files, and updated the question to include a sample of the code that successfully starts the deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your answer covers the solution it does not explain why the new set of roles that you provided are working successfully in contrast to the previous ones.

The `can-i` command was a bit misleading in this case. Result of it, was in fact correct since with this role you were able to delete but only chosen/mentioned resources. Since you used  `resourceNames` with an empty list `[""]`, your role did not allow to delete anything.

To simply test this I placed the exact deployment name in the `resourceNames`:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: live-serviceaccount-role
  namespace: live
rules:
- apiGroups: ["","apps"] 
  resources: ["services", "services/", "deployment", "deployment/", "service", "service/", "deployments", "deployments/"]
  resourceNames: ["live-stream-deploy-testing123"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "create", "list", "delete"]
```

Once I did that I launched your code and deployment was successfully deleted.
So to sum up You should either fill the `resourceNames` with names of resources or omit it completely.

Comment: You are correct.  I should not have had the resourceNames as an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct role definition that works for me:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: live-serviceaccount-role
  namespace: live
rules:
- apiGroups: ["","apps"] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete"]
```

Which produces this can-i output:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i --as=system:serviceaccount:live:live-serviceaccount  --list -n live
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
deployments                                     []                  []               [create delete]
deployments.apps                                []                  []               [create delete]
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
                                                [/api/*]            []               [get]
                                                [/api]              []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]           []               [get]
                                                [/apis]             []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/livez]            []               [get]
                                                [/livez]            []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]        []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]          []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]           []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]           []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
```